# How do I view console output on Apple Watch when not connected to the debugger?

Tags: xcode, logging, console, apple-watch

So I'm trying to track down an issue that crops up when I'm *NOT* debugging with Xcode on the Apple watch, and I've discovered that the Apple Watch has some serious problems with console output if it wasn't launched via the debugger. Given the following code:

```
- (IBAction)onPrint:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"############## Printing! ##################");
    printf("************** Printf! ******************\n");
}
```

When launching via the debugger, it shows both lines in Xcode's console window. Great, no problems there.

If, however, I launch the watch app manually (from the watch itself), I get nothing in the console log via the devices window in Xcode, and nothing in the Console app on the mac (other than the normal "kernel[0] : prevent idle sleep list" messages the watch emits to the console from time to time).

I also tried connecting to the watch extension process using the Debug -> Attach to Process menu in Xcode, but it still won't print anything. Clear console, reload console... nothing works. I've looked all over SO for answers, and tried everything marked as an accepted answer or not, but nothing seems to work. This app is as simple as it can get: A single button that executes the code above to print to the console.

Is it just broken? Or is there some other arcane magic I must weave? I'm running Xcode 8.1 and WatchOS 3.1 on an Apple Watch 2.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out Karl? Just a limitation of watchOS?

Comment: I am also struggling with the same problem @Karl. I am using Xcode 12 and WatchOS 7 but not able to get the logs without Xcode debug process.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is just a limitation of WatchOS. The only way I've been able to get data back is by storing logs in a file and then fetching the file later.

Answer (score 1):

Thing that can help you is called sysanalyse: you'll have to add special profile to both iPhone and Watch, and this will allow to see your app's logs in Console and via sysanalyse reports. Instructions and profiles are provided [here](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/).
If you are debugging background tasks, important to know: watchos's daemon will not terminate process what had already used it's background execution time limit if it is connected to debugger.

Answer (score 0):

This is really odd because I was able to see log statements on the console. It's just now, I'm not. This is for Watch OS 6, xcode 11.2.1.